# How to create an application that listens to windows events?

Tags: windows, delphi

How do i write a windows application that listens to particular keys strokes to launch it! just the way google desktop app works,press ctrl twice and it pop up!

I would prefer examples in delphi, but i dont mind other languages to!

*For starters i assume it should be a service running in windows (i can be able to create a service application)*

Gath

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909745/how-to-create-an-application-that-listens-to-windows-events ?

Comment: This one has more answers, so maybe it is best to close the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/install_a_keyboard_hook.html

http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/keyboard_hook.htm

Comment: RegisterHotkey! Don't install a global hook!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off registering a hotkey instead of installing a gobal keyboard hook:

http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0601_3.htm

Comment: Can you configure a hotkey to respond like Google Desktop Search does to pressing Ctrl twice?

Answer (score 1):

See HotKeyManager at: 
http://subsimple.com/delphi.asp

Answer (score 0):

make a service that install global keyboard hook .

Comment: Why would it need to be a service instead of an ordinary program?

Answer (score -1):

You could write it as a service if you wish with its own message pump, capturing all windows messages, checking those that are related to key presses and not passing them on to the default message handler.

My Delphi is very rusty (version 4), so I can't say how to do it.

An easy alternative to writing a service, in C# would be to set an application form with Opacity of 0%, KeyPreview = True and ShowInTaskbar=False.

Maybe your version of Delphi has something similar.

Comment: Does setting KeyPreview make the window receive ALL keyboard events from the system? I doubt it. It just makes the window receive keyboard events before the controls on that window, the same as Delphi's KeyPreview property. That makes it no good for Gath's problem.

Comment: Quite true.
I'll admit that I posted without thinking. 
Damn cold giving me a definite case of fuzzy logic. 
Sorry.